# Anonymizing users, without anonymizing moderators

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the code

```
$(".name").html("john");
```

I am able to change all names on the page to john, this is fantastic and makes my life easy. 
 However, I need to be able to retain the names of my mods from the function. How do I go about setting exceptions?

```
$(".name:not(.mod)").html("john");
```

Will not work, because a mod class is only added when they have their mod tag on, and most of the time, they leave them off, and simply use their name.

Comment: You'll have to tell how you set mods apart on the page. Also, note that this isn't very effective in actually anonymizing names. The user can just view the page source and see the original content.

Comment: It's purely superficial, for the users who don't want to see names, the page html doesn't actually need to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no actual data apart from their name that would discern mods from other users, the only way is to pick them out by hand.

```
$(".name").filter( function() {
    return $(this).text() !== 'Mary Moderator' 
        && $(this).text() !== 'Aaron Admin'; 
     // && ...
}).html("john");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WQDpb/

Comment: that would be the answer I was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: @user2487967 I would just like to note this is not future-proof and you should rethink the way you construct your page. By going down this route you are saying that no two people will ever have the same name. Whilst it may not happen often it certainly can. It is also much harder to maintain and is likely to result in much redundant code.

Comment: Moderators use a secure method for their name, which can't be copied by normal users.
I've been kind of vague with my span's, but regardless, I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".name:not(.mod)").html("john");
```

Simply give the mods a class and use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to filter them out.

If you need to alter the names first and then revert them use `jQuery.data()`:

```
$(".name").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.data(this, "name", $this.html());
   $this.html("john");
});
```

You can now retrieve the original name by using:

```
var name = $.data(el, "name");
```

Comment: Oh, whoops, forgot to mention why I couldn't do that. One moment, going to edit question

Comment: @user2487967 So there is nothing different between a regular name and a mods name? Then you can't create an exception for them.